# how to citate properly in quarto

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, quarto, citations

I use quarto to write a thesis and want to add citations. With the insert function I can directly search for some works in my Zotero library. It then generates itself the .bib file with the citations. When I render it, it font show the citations in the bottom and also the citations in the brackets stay the same. The generated .bib file is of course in the same folder as the .qmd file. Also the .bib file is not empty.

[image]

In the text its marked like that:

[image]

But when rendering it won't show the citations in the bottom. Only in the text with the same brackets:

[image]

deleted the .bib file and tried it again. Still not working

Comment: Can you share your yaml header?